# How to upsert a postgresql table from a postgresql view of same DB?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, view

I have created a table with columns similar to an existing view, I'm thinking of upserting the view data to the table using a python script and also add a new column with the data inserted timestamp to the table so that I can use that as a flag to delete the old data from the table. But i coudnt find related links or formulate the query to do a batch upsert from a view to table, can somebody share their expertise?

Comment: Why? A view gets its data from other tables, so why not work on the original table(s).

Comment: The original table's data are nested and the view has unnested data. While doing join with that view it's very slow so I thought an indexed table would solve the issue.

Comment: 1) All current versions(10+) of Postgres support [Materialized View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-creatematerializedview.html) which allows you to decide when the view query is run. 2) An `UPSERT`(`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`) is just a query. See here [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) for *Examples* in *Notes* section. 3) I would add a trigger to the table that updates the inserted timestamp field.

Comment: Hi Adrian, Thanks for your comment. I'm looking for a query that's something like 'upsert into my_table (select *, timestamp from my_view)" is there something like this?

Comment: An `UPSERT` in Postgres is the statement `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`. Read [On CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) and look at the *EXAMPLES* at bottom of page. `INSERT INTO ...` can have sub-query supply the values. FYI, in Postgres 15+ there is [MERGE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html).